# VPS сервер не доступен с рабочего ПК

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, vps

Есть VPS сервер (Ubuntu) на котором запущено два сервиса Node js слушающих 8081 и 8082 порт (запущены только ради теста и возвращают строку текста).
В iptables настроено перенаправление с 80 порта на 8081 и открыты 8081 и 8082 порты.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiports --sports 8081,8082 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiports --dports 8081,8082 -j ACCEPT
```

На время теста выключен фаервол, антивирус Windows defender, сетью управляет какая-то аутсорсинговая контора и по их заверениям никаких блокировок нет, то же самое утверждает тех. поддержка провайдера.

Сама проблема заключается в том что с ПК могу подключиться только к 80 порту остальные не отвечают, но если пробовать например с телефона зайти на порты 8081(2) все корректно работает.

В таких вопросах опыта не так много, надеюсь на подсказки сообщества в какую сторону копать.

Comment: запустите `tcpdump -n -i ethX port 8081`, где ethX интерфейс сервера, смотрящий в интернет. после этого обратитесь снаружи на на порт 8081. Если вы в выводе tcpdump увидите эти попытки - значит пакеты дошли и надо искать проблему в настройках вашего сервера (скорее все таки в iptables). Если пакеты не появились, значит их не пропустил кто то из провайдеров в цепочке между вами и сервером (возможно какая нибудь защита даже у хостера дающего vps) (или все таки ваша винда, что маловероятно, т.к. исходящие запросы ничего обычно не режет)

Comment: @Mike Если запускать команду которую Вы предложили и зайти с рабочего ПК, то нет никакой реакции, если с другого то все нормально.
Буду дальше тех. поддержку напрягать.

Comment: Имейте ввиду, резать может и хостер, может какие то сети у него в черном списке и он от туда не пускает лишнее ...